# When REBUILDing indexes on SQL Server, what bearing does tempdb & LOG disk speed have?

Tags: sql-server, index, transaction-log, tempdb

Say I have the a data disk that is 50x faster than the LOG and tempdb (measured by Random Write speed) disk. (Don't ask why that's something we'll be fixing if needed)

I have a table that's got 19 million rows with about 30 indexes (so basically non trivial).

How much of a factor would the disk speed of the LOG & tempdb than if I was to have the same disk speeds as the data disk.

**Edit:**
Some more stats.

**We have moved the LOG to the RAID data drive as test and unfortunately there was not improvement in the speed of the the REBUILD. It still too 1 hour.**

- tempdb is on it's own Raid10 array
- LOG    is on it's own Raid10 array
- Data   is on it's own Raid10 array
- RAM > 100 Gb (yes 100Gb) and no limit on SQL using it for data or index creation

Note this is not a transactional system, rather a Data Warehouse.

Comment: how much RAM do you have in the system?  what kind of disks are we talking about; RAID or single disks?

Comment: @MaxVernon - i've edited the question.

Comment: so, you are rebuilding 30 indexes with 19 millions rows in under an hour?

Comment: Yes about an hour

Comment: As ALTER INDEX REBUILD can be minimally logged with the BULK logged recovery model, can you consider switching models for the sake of a faster rebuild?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will see if that's possible in the given architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexes are treated the same as any other data modification i.e. they are written to the log.  The performance of your log will directly impact the performance of all writes to your database.  If your LOG drive is 50 times slower that your data drive, you have serious performance limitations and should consider rectifying that as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks man. Please see my update. We've just repeated our test after moving the log. It still took 1 hour.

Comment: move the log file to a dedicated drive, preferably a dedicated RAID 10 array.  Move TempDB to an SSD.

Comment: 19,000,000 X 30 = 570,000,000 index entries.  Not knowing the column types, I am guessing there is a lot of string data.  Doing all that in one hour is pretty good, in my humble opinion.